# Devise not saving custom controller 'update' action for Array attribute

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got two devise models - User and Agent - so I've got custom controllers for each.

In the Agent controller, when updating the Agent, I'm trying to pass in `user_ids`, which is an Array:

```
  def account_update_params
    params["agent"]["user_ids"] = params["agent"]["user_ids"].split(",")
    params.require(:agent).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, {:user_ids => [:id]})
  end
```

Before I added `[:id]` to `user_ids`, I was receiving an 'unpermitted parameter' error message. Adding `[:id]` solved that issue, but now my issue is that **the record is not saving at all**, and `user_ids` remains as `nil`.

It is being passed in the parameters though, as you can see here:

```
"agent"=>{"user_ids"=>"3", "email"=>"test_agent@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code handling the update of the `agent` instance (the place where you assign `user_ids` and save the record)

Comment: The controller just inherits its update action from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and uses the `account_update_params` with a `before_action`.